# How to put a picture to the top right of a page?

Tags: diagrams

I have written in TeX the following:

```
\section{A}
... somethingA ...

\begin{picture}(100, 100)(-250, -110)
\includegraphics[scale=1]{face.png}
\end{picture}

\section{B}
... somethingB ...
```

I have put specific parameters in picture `(-250, -110)` so that the picture is added in the top right of the created page. Although this works just fine, `face.png` appears where I want it, the problem is that there is a big gap between `somethingA` and `somethingB`. So I have something like this in the created document:

```
... somethingA ...





... somethingB ...
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

1. Using the [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) package:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
   \usepackage{eso-pic} 
   \usepackage{lipsum} 

   \begin{document}
   \lipsum[1-3]
   \AddToShipoutPicture*
       {\put(500,700){\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{image}}}
   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

2. Using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{lipsum} 

   \begin{document}
   \lipsum[1-3]
   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
     \node[xshift=-3cm,yshift=-2cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{image}};
   \end{tikzpicture}

   \end{document}
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the package `wrapfig` might solve your problem.

Try this code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document} 

\section{A}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3cm}
\includegraphics{test} 
\end{wrapfigure}

\blindtext


\section{B}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: wrapfigure]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was just looking for something you provided. Very useful and to the point.